# Refresh One Pivot with Shared Cache

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I'm having issues with a macro that should allow me to refresh pivot tables and avoid the overlapping error message. I thought I found a sneaky way to give the appearance of this happening but am running into a issue with shared data source.

---

I have 5 pivot tables (each with the same data source: `Table1`) in the below structure

```
Column A
----------
Pivot 1
'Two Blank Rows
Pivot 2
'Two Blank Rows
Pivot 3 
'Two Blank Rows
Pivot 4
'Two Blank Rows
Pivot 5
'Two Blank ROws
```

The macro aims to move `Pivot 1` over 6 columns, refresh that pivot alone (allowing it to expand or compress as much as needed). Then the macro moves `Pivot 2` over 6 columns and situates it two rows below the first pivot, refresh that pivot alone, etc. The process repeats for all pivots and then I delete the 6 columns giving the impression that all tables are back in their original starting point except the table rows have expanded/compressed accordingly without running into the issue of `ERROR: A pivot table cannot overlap another pivot table`. When `ScreenUpdating` is toggled off, this gives the impression that pivots are refreshing and dynamically adjusting their position to allow for expansion/compression of the surrounding tables.

---

The issue I am having is that when I refresh one pivot, the other 4 automatically try to refresh which produces the overlap error for the other 4 tables. **How can I only refresh one pivot table at a time despite a common Pivot Cache?**

I have tried the two lines of code in center of loop and I have tried to use a macro found on [this](http://excelunplugged.com/2013/06/05/how-do-i-separate-pivottables/) link that aims to break apart the shared pivot cache allowing for independent refreshes. The macro on this link just crashes my instance of excel each time.

```
For i = LBound(OTCPvts) To UBound(OTCPvts)
    LRow = OTC.Range("O" & OTC.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(3).Row
    OTC.PivotTables(OTCPvts(i)).TableRange2.Cut OTC.Range("M" & LRow)
    On Error Resume Next

        OTC.PivotTables(OTCPvts(i)).PivotCache.Refresh 'Gives Overlap Error
        OTC.PivotTables(OTCPvts(i)).RefreshTable 'Does not refresh/change table

    On Error GoTo 0
Next i
```

*Showing relevant code only - the process goes on to filter/sort before moving on to `Next i` but this all works fine*

Comment: I suppose one workaround would be to put all tables side by side first, then just refresh all, and then put them back in desired order. Either way, wondering if anyone else has an idea on how to fix the problem as is

Comment: I was actually about to suggest that, as I had a similar problem not too long ago that I had resolved the same way. I couldn't figure out a way to only refresh one single pivot table when the cache is shared either. Hopefully we both learn something today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, upon revisiting this, I discovered another kind of hacky workaround that doesn't involve moving the tables more than once. While refreshing a shared pivot cache seems to update all of the pivot tables sharing the cache, you could apply an `xlTopCount` filter with a value of `1` to all of them before refreshing, then move each table and remove the filter

```
For i = LBound(OTCPvts) To UBound(OTCPvts)
    With OTC.PivotTables(OTCPvts(i))
        .ClearAllFilters
        .PivotFields("FieldName").PivotFilters.Add2 _
            Type:=xlTopCount, DataField:=.PivotFields("OtherFieldName"), Value1:=1
        .PivotCache.Refresh
        .RefreshTable
    End With
Next i
For i = LBound(OTCPvts) To UBound(OTCPvts)
    With OTC.PivotTables(OTCPvts(i))
        lRow = OTC.Range("O" & OTC.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(3).Row
        .TableRange2.Cut OTC.Range("M" & lRow)
        .ClearAllFilters
    End With
Next i
```

Turns out neither changing/refreshing the pivot cache or refreshing the table removes a filter, so this is a good way to prevent overlapping by forcing your table's size until it's been moved and the filter removed.